# Permission denied while calling 'convert' command from PHP

Tags: php, apache, permissions, imagick

I am trying to use ImageMagick from PHP. I installed ImageMagick and the PHP extension on a virtual CentOS Server. Executing the `convert` command from bash works as expected. 
If I make a PHP file with the content

```
<?php exec('convert /home/vagrant/test/image.jpg -resize 200x200 /home/vagrant/test/image_converted.jpg'); ?>
```

and call it in PHP using the command line `php convert.php` it works as well.
But if I start my Apache server and try to access the page trough my browser it returns the error:

```
convert: unable to open image `/home/vagrant/test/image.jpg': Permission denied @ blob.c/OpenBlob/2480.
convert: missing an image filename `/home/vagrant/test/image_converted.jpg' @ convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2800.
```

So, I thought it might be about permissions. Calling `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` showed processes of a user named apache, so I assume that's the server. So I tried changing ownership to this user

```
sudo chown -R apache /home/vagrant/test/
```

Again, calling the website I get the error messages. Then I tried giving all users full access

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/vagrant/test/
```

-->    `drwxrwxrwx. 2 apache vagrant      4096 Dec 21 16:56 test`

Again, the same error occurred. What am I doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only change the permissions for the subdirectory. If apache has insufficient privileges for home or home/vargrant, you won't be able to access the file.

You can check if a user has sufficient privileges using sudo:

```
sudo -u apache cp /home/vagrant/test/image.jpg /home/vagrant/test/image_converted.jpg
```

Comment: Great! You're absolutely right. I didn't use permissions much until now... One question you might be able to answer then as well: My website folder is `/var/www/html` and symlinked to some other folder (/vagrant). What is the most sensible way to set the permissions? Make apache the owner of `/var`? or set permissions to some (which?) number?